# Where Clause using lambda always returns true in Unit Testing

Tags: c#

I have a table with 2 columns.

```
| DealerCode | TransactionID |
| 222223     | 98766         |
```

and i have this method that returns a list

```
public List<Transaction> GetCurrentTransaction(string dealerCode, string transactionId)
    {
        return context.Transactions.Where(c => c.DealerCode == dealerCode && (c.TransactionID == transactionId)).ToList();
    }
```

however everytime i tried to unit test it, it always display true, as you can see in my testing, i purposedly created a wrong parameter so that it would fail.

```
Assert.IsNotNull(tran.GetCurrentTransaction("2222231", "987661"));
```

i have tried searching thru the forums and googling to no avail.

Comment: That would return an empty list which is by definition not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method returns an instance of List, and even though it contains no items (since there are no records matching the criteria), the list itself is still created, and therefore, not equal to NULL, and thats the reason your unittest passes.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add a `Assert.IsNotEmpty` assert - http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=conditionAsserts&r=2.2.8

Answer (score 1):

If you use MSTest you can add:

```
Assert.IsTrue(tran.GetCurrentTransaction("2222231", "987661").Any());
```

`Any()` checks if there are objects in a list. A functional unit test would also specify the condition in the Any.

Answer (score 0):

@ChaosPandion had it right in his comment. Your GetCurrentTransaction method will always return an instance of a list (which is not null). In the case where there are no matches that list will contain no items. You could use code similar to the following to get the result that you are after.

```
Assert.IsTrue(tran.GetCurrentTransaction("2222231", "987661").Any());
```